# Angular option with ngModel does not display default option when paired with the value property

Tags: angular, forms, drop-down-menu, html-select, angular2-ngmodel

I have a list of types in my component.ts as followed.

```
  public type: string;
  types:Array<Object> = [
      {name: "Category", value: "c"},
      {name: "Cuisine", value: "a"},
      {name: "Main Ingredient", value: "i"},
  ];
```

And here is the corresponding HTML code.

```
<select class="form-control" id="queryTypeSelect" [(ngModel)]="type" name="queryTypeSelectForm"> 
    <option *ngFor="let typ of types" [value]="typ.value">{{ typ.name }}</option>
</select>
```

In the constructor, I have initialized "type" like this:

```
  constructor(
    private recipeService: RecipeService, 
    private apiService: ApiService) { 
      this.type = this.types[0]["name"];

  }
```

But when loading the page, the select bar shows nothing, until I manually select something. Although when selecting, the default item shows as checked (the first entry).

Why is this happening? When I remove the value property from the option, it shows the default entry alright. But I need to have the value property.

What is going wrong here? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, you should use
`this.type = this.types[0]["value"];`

Angular Forms will compare ther Selects ngModel with each options [value] to select the preselected option.

While you use `types[0]["name"]`, Angular has no chance to match your preselected value with the correct option.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" id="queryTypeSelect"  name="queryTypeSelectForm"> 
    <option *ngFor="let typ of types"    
            [selected]="typ.name === type"
            [ngValue]="typ.value"
   >{{ typ.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If I use this, how do I get the selected value upon form submission?

Comment: put in a ngModel in the select component.  https://dev.to/jwp/angular-validation-using-ngmodel-55gf